# angularjs datatable overflow

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

I have problem on display datatable. It overflows like in the picture.

[image]

I already tried `withOption('autoWidth', false)`, but still not fix.

my html

```
<form class="bv-form" name="datagridForm" ng-submit="gridSubmitHandler(datagridForm, $event)" novalidate="novalidate">
<table class="inner-dataTable table table-striped nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions"
    dt-columns="dtColumns" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs" dt-instance="dtInstanceCallback" id="{{getTableDomId()}}">
</table>
```

js code

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function() {
              var defer = $q.defer();
              defer.resolve($scope.tableData);
              return defer.promise;
            })
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
            .withOption('oLanguage', {
                oPaginate: {
                    sFirst: "<<",
                    sLast: ">>",
                    sNext: ">",
                    sPrevious: "<"
                }
            })
            .withOption('responsive', {details: {
                // TODO: add configuration in application.xml to determine columns which should stay visible, like Actions:
                //   https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/classes
                // Doing something like keeping Actions visible on the far right is not really supported yet, the configuration would need to be a bit complex.
                // Some discussion here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/22700/responsive-shows-hidden-columns-again/p2
                renderer: responsiveRendererFn
            }}).withOption('autoWidth', false)
            .withOption('createdRow', function(row, data, dataIndex) {
                $(row).addClass("" + data.id);
                CommonFactory.coloringRow(data.statusCode, null, row);
                $compile(row)($scope);
            })
            .withOption('preDrawCallback', preDraw)
            .withOption('deferRender', true)
```

Thanks

Comment: Check the container width of the datatable

Comment: We need to see the code to be able to solve that ...

Comment: @SophonMen please show us your html and css code

Comment: I have edited my question with more coding. thanks

Comment: What is the width of the form container? Itself and its parents